# Azure mutliple VM in a single VM

Tags: azure, blockchain

I am wondering whether it is possible to run multiple VM's within a single VM. Basically I am looking at doing some research for an upcoming university subject. I want to run a mini blockchain style environment, and I need multiple VM's to test this.

What do you think is my best approach? A single cloud service with multiple machines? or am I required to purchase every single VM that I will require?

Comment: Did I get it correctly that you add `blockchain` tag in accordance with its definition at `stackoverflow`?

Comment: This is a question for ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can't. The virtualization software requires access to a set of specific CPU resources which are not in turn virtualized inside a VM it creates. Thus, you have three options

- rent as many VM's as you need;
- build a test environment yourself using any PC equipped with an [Intel CPU supporting VT-x](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology), or AMD
  CPU supporting [AMD-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#AMD_virtualization_.28AMD-V.29);
- run a full X86 emulator (as many instances
  as needed) on a physical or virtual PC. One of such implementations
  is open sourced project [BOCSH](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/).

The last option would have a very big performance issues of course.